# Parse JSON object with unknown keys in Java

Tags: java, json, parsing

I'm working on a little program that matches available scrabble letters with words in the dictionary. I found [a neat JSON file](https://github.com/adambom/dictionary) that includes most words in the english language and now I want to parse it and create a Word object (with a name and definition value) for each word in it. The format is quite different from the JSON file I'm used to work with and I'm not sure how to proceed. For each word, the word itself is the key and the definition is the value. I'd like to parse it in a way that gives me both the key and the value, so that I can use them to make a new Word object.

Here's the format of the json file (extremely shortened just to give you the general gist.

```
{"DIPLOBLASTIC":"Characterizing the ovum when it has two primary germinallayers.","DEFIGURE":"To delineate. [Obs.]These two stones as they are here defigured. Weever.","LOMBARD":"Of or pertaining to Lombardy, or the inhabitants of Lombardy."}
```

What would be the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: What's the question, exactly? Please read the [ask] page for more help on writing questions.

Comment: what you want is a map

Comment: A [mcve] of what you've tried so far will definitely help here. Also, what do you mean by "the format is quite different from the JSON files I'm used to work with"? It just looks like standard JSON to me?

Comment: @berry120: I'm used to having static key labels where I can just get the values by using the same key, here the keys are dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String json = "{\"DIPLOBLASTIC\":\"Characterizing the ovum when it has two primary germinallayers.\",\"DEFIGURE\":\"To delineate. [Obs.]These two stones as they are here defigured. Weever.\",\"LOMBARD\":\"Of or pertaining to Lombardy, or the inhabitants of Lombardy.\"}";

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            HashMap<String,String> map = mapper.readValue(json, HashMap.class);
            for(Map.Entry e : map.entrySet()){
                System.out.println(e.getKey() + ":" + e.getValue());
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

output

```
DEFIGURE:To delineate. [Obs.]These two stones as they are here defigured. Weever.
DIPLOBLASTIC:Characterizing the ovum when it has two primary germinallayers.
LOMBARD:Of or pertaining to Lombardy, or the inhabitants of Lombardy.
```